# Safari downloads slow until download is restarted

Tags: macos, safari

Very frequently when I am downloading a file, I notice that it downloads very slowly on Safari. This occurs from just about any website I am downloading a file from. However, after a restart of the download (canceling and then restarting it), the download starts and resumes at full speed.

This has occurred to me on macOS High Sierra, and now occurs to me on macOS Mojave.

Is there any reason Safari does this? The only extension I have enabled is uBlock Origin.

Comment: When you disable uBlock does this still happen?

Comment: Good question. I'll have to test that out.

Comment: After restarting the download, is it faster throughout or only in the beginning? If it is only faster in the beginning it could be caused by caching.

Comment: It's faster through the whole download. It's rather odd behavior

Comment: This used to happen to me from time to time, then I noticed it only happened with mp3 files and I realized my ISP was throttling my data when I was downloading files it did not approve of. It hasn't happened in quite a while but I imagine a VPN woul fix my problem. I wonder if that might be happening to you.

Comment: @SteveChambers the strange thing is, in my experience, it happens with any file from any server, plus it goes back to its original speed when restarting. Maybe a problem with uBlock.

Comment: Yah, that does not sound like ISP packet shaping (filetering) Turn off extensions and try another browser. You could also reset Safari to defaults, but save your bookmarks first.

Comment: Resetting Safari might do the trick, thank you. I've had data from Safari from who knows back when